# how to register for distribution in iphone

Tags: iphone

i m new in iphone and i have problem for distribution of application.
actually i have one p.c. which support 3.0 to 3.1.2 version which is register for distribution.
but another p.c. which i upgrade to 4.0 then how i register for distribute from upgraded p.c.
i have distribution certificate of lower version.

Comment: Honestly, i dont understand your question. What do you mean with p.c.? A Mac? I'm guessing, you have two development machines, one with SDK 3.1.2 and the other one with SDK 4.0? Guessing again, you cannot sign your applications any more with the 4.0 machine. First of all your distribution certificate (including its private key) have nothing to do with the Version of the SDK you are using and if my assumptions are correct you have to copy your private key from the first machine to the upgraded machine by exporting it from your keychain. If i'm wrong, provide some more information please.

Comment: OOOOhhhh! You mean a (p)rovisioning (c)ertificate :) !!!! Got it!
Well then, Winders answer should help...

Answer (score 2):

In your target build settings set the `iPhone OS Deployment Target` setting to 3.0 and the `Base SDK` setting to 4.0. This will let you use the latest SDK to build apps for devices still running 3.0.  You wont be able to use any of the features added in later SDK versions but it will run on the older devices.